# How to calculate coefficient of static friction given certain data

Tags: physics, classical-mechanics

I'm trying to work out a question where I need to calculate the coefficient of friction given the radius of the corner, the angle of the bank and the speed at which the corner can be taken.

Specifically the question says

> A speedway has banked turns of 31° and a radius of 304.8 m. Drivers can go through the corners at a speed of 322 km/h before slipping. What is the coefficient of friction between the tires and the road?

Is there a generic formula that I could use? If not could I get some help working this out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a question about physics, not about mathematics and is better suited to physics stack exchange

Comment: best delete this question after reposting it

Comment: It's a valid question in the Classical Mechanics category, so there's no need to delete it. Do you want an answer?

Comment: I think in physics.SE they'll not answer this question. Questions in Physics.SE that belong to homework should ask to specific concepts in the physics of the problem and _not_  how the math o the problem should be used. Usually.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of [a banked turn with friction is worked out on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banked_turn#Banked_turn_with_friction), where the following equation for maximal velocity is derived:
$$
v= {\sqrt{rg\left(\sin \theta +\mu_s \cos \theta \right)\over \cos \theta -\mu_s \sin \theta }}
={\sqrt{rg\left(\tan\theta +\mu_s\right)\over 1 -\mu_s \tan\theta}}.
$$

This equation expresses the maximum velocity $v$ in terms of the angle of incline $\theta$, coefficient $\mu_s$ of static friction, and radius $r$ of curvature; $g\approx9.8\,{\rm m}/{\rm s}^2$.

Squaring both sides of the equation and isolating $\mu_s$ we find
$$
\mu_s = {v^2-rg\tan\theta\over v^2\tan\theta+rg}.
$$
Now it remains to substitute the given values:
$$
\theta=31^\circ, \quad
v=322\,{\rm km}/{\rm h}\approx 89.44\,{\rm m}/{\rm s}, \quad
r=304.8\,{\rm m}, \quad
g\approx9.8\,{\rm m}/{\rm s}^2.
$$
Substitution yields
$$
\mu_s \approx 0.796
$$

Comment: Note that this is not static friction, is the kinetic friction coefficient

Comment: The words "before slipping" in the problem statement mean that the wheels *do not slip up the incline*, so $\mu_s$ applies to our case.